# VirtualBox error VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am using Fedora 12, with kernel `stv-fedora 2.6.31.12-174.2.22.fc12.i686`

I have install VirtualBox OSE v3.1.4-1.fc12.  When I start VirtualBox I get the following error:

```
Failed to start the virtual machine WinXP32.
Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-eth0' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
One of the kernel modules was not successfully loaded. Make sure that no 
  kernel modules from an older version of VirtualBox exist. Then try to
  recompile and reload the kernel modules by executing '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
  as root (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
```

However, if I run `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` I get this error:

```
-bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory
```

How do I get rid of the error and run VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to type:

```
sudo modprobe vboxnetftl
```

Comment: On my system (Arch Linux), the module was called `vboxnetflt` O.O (noticed the switched `t` and `l`).